# Singleton Class vs Statemangement tool like Redux for App State

Tags: mobile, redux, frontend, provider, state-management

Can somebody explain to me why you would ever use a statemanagement tool like Redux or the Provider library instead of just creating your own Singleton class to hold the state of your application?

Comment: I think you are right, I don't understand either. It does seem an unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is so much more than a singleton. It gives you pub/sub, time-traveling to prior states (especially good for debugging) and an open-ended api to plug in your own functionality. It is an especially good place to handle side effects.

In react, you can't just "plug in" your own data structure and expect everything to update properly. React updates on an as-needed basis. In order to do that, you *have* to use the React api in one form or another (context api, hooks, etc.).

Any singleton implementation you do will essentially be a subset of redux's functionality. In an overwhelming majority of cases, you will need all of redux's features (along with 3rd party middlewares) in a long-term production application.